# Why does my delete/destroy method and link not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, destroy

In my Ruby on Rails application I have the destroy method in films_controller:

```
before_action :set_film, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def destroy
    @film = Film.find(params[:id])
    @film.destroy
    redirect_to films_path
end
```

Which is getting the params from film_params in films_controller:

```
private

def film_params
    params.require(:film).permit(:title, :synopsis, :length, :director, :cast1, :cast2, :cast3, :release_date, :warnings, :certificate)
end

def set_film
  @film = Film.find(params[:id])
end
```

And I am calling this method in my index.html.erb page:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', film_path(film), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

But whenever I click the "Destroy" button it sends me to the **show.html.erb** page, which is as follows:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id="contentWrapper">
     <div id="content">
         <div class='film'>
            <div class='large_panel film'>
                <h1><%= @film.title %></h1>
                <div class="bbfc-icons">
                    <!-- <img src="/images/bbfc/15.png" alt="15" height="40" width="40"> -->
                    <% if not @film.certificate.blank? %>
                        <%= @film.certificate.age_rating %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
                <% if not @film.image_url.blank? %>
                    <%= image_tag @film.image_url,:size => "900x250" %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= image_tag "coming_soon.jpg",:size => "900x250" %>
                <% end %>   
                <div>
                    <div class='film_info_two_column_left'>
                        <div class='info'>
                            INFO<br>
                        </div>                    
                        <p><span class="fontBold">Starring:</span><br><% if not @film.cast1.blank? %><%= @film.cast1 %><% end %><% if not @film.cast2.blank? %>, <%= @film.cast2 %><% end %><% if not @film.cast3.blank? %>, and <%= @film.cast3 %></p><% end %>
                        <p><span class="fontBold">Director:</span> <%= @film.director %></p>
                        <p><span class="fontBold">Running Time:</span> <%= @film.length %></p>
                        <p><span class="fontBold">Certificate:</span> 15</p>          
                        <br/>
                        <p class="filmQuote whiteText"><span>SYNOPSIS:<br/></span><p>
                        <p class="filmSynopsis"><% if not @film.synopsis.blank? %><%= @film.synopsis %><% end %>                    
                    </div>
                    <div class='film_info_two_column_right time'>
                        <div class="info">
                            SCREENING TIMES
                        </div>
                        <div class="screeningTimes">
                            <% if not @film.showings.blank? %>
                                This film is shown at the following times:</p>
                                <!-- Group the showings by date, so that if there are two showings on the same date the date is only displayed once -->
                                <% @film.showings.group_by{|showing| showing.show_date.strftime("%A %e %B %Y") }.to_a.each do |showing| %>
                                    <!-- Display the times for that date in hours and minutes, joining them with a comma in between each time -->
                                    <%= showing.first %><br><%= showing.last.map{|s| s.show_time.strftime("%H:%M")}.join(', ')  %></p>            
                                <% end %>
                            <% else %>
                                <p>There are currently no showings for this film.</p>
                            <% end %>
                        </div>
                        </p><%= link_to 'All Films', films_path %> | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_film_path(@film) %>
                    </div>
                    <div class='clearfix'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my **routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'films/index'

    resources :films
    resources :showings
    root 'films#index'
end
```

Output from running    rake routes:

```
 H:\Sites\ThorCinema\Under Construction\ThorCinema>rake routes
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
 films_index GET    /films/index(.:format)       films#index
       films GET    /films(.:format)             films#index
             POST   /films(.:format)             films#create
    new_film GET    /films/new(.:format)         films#new
   edit_film GET    /films/:id/edit(.:format)    films#edit
        film GET    /films/:id(.:format)         films#show
             PATCH  /films/:id(.:format)         films#update
             PUT    /films/:id(.:format)         films#update
             DELETE /films/:id(.:format)         films#destroy
    showings GET    /showings(.:format)          showings#index
             POST   /showings(.:format)          showings#create
 new_showing GET    /showings/new(.:format)      showings#new
edit_showing GET    /showings/:id/edit(.:format) showings#edit
     showing GET    /showings/:id(.:format)      showings#show
             PATCH  /showings/:id(.:format)      showings#update
             PUT    /showings/:id(.:format)      showings#update
             DELETE /showings/:id(.:format)      showings#destroy
        root GET    /                            films#index
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? I have followed the [guidelines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) exactly but cannot get the delete to work. Can someone please help, this still isn't working.

Comment: Are your routes set up?  What do you get from `rake routes | grep destroy | grep film`?

Comment: I have added my routes. How do I show the output from rake routes?

Comment: You can goto terminal in your app directory and then run command over there with `rake routes` and paste output over here.

Comment: I can't copy and paste from the rails cmd though

Comment: You probably can.  What operating system are you using?  Ie windows, mac, linux?

Comment: Windows 7, when I right-click on the cmd "copy" is blanked out

Comment: This any use?  You'll need to crack copying and pasting to/from the command line so you might as well try and get it working now   http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/   http://windows7themes.net/en-us/how-to-copy-text-from-command-prompt/

Comment: Could you paste how does the rendered linked look like? It should contain `data-method="delete"`

Comment: Where can I find the rendered link?

Comment: Added the output from running rake routes

Comment: Use the web inspector tool in whatever browser you're using.  If it's chrome then right click on the link and choose "inspect element".  or, look in the page source.

Comment: What am I looking for?

Comment: This is what it says in Chrome for delete when clicking view page source <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/films/23">Destroy</a>

Comment: @benjs.1 Are there any before actions in the controller (or up the chain) that might redirect you to the show action? You can check the log if you're being redirected.

Comment: You mean in the films_ controller are there other methods before destroy? If that's what you mean then yes, there's the index, new, create, update, and show method before the destroy in the controller file. Should I put destroy at the top?

Comment: @benjs.1 No, I was talking about [`before actions (filters)`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

Comment: I added:    before_action :set_film, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] at the beginning of the controller and  private
 
     def set_film
      @film = Film.find(params[:id])
    end

At the bottom, but it still isn't working

Comment: can you show me the link that is generated as html. Is it like this `<a href='http://localhost:3000/showings/1/destroy' ...>Destroy</a>`

Comment: When clicking Inspect Element on it, this is shown:      <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/films/1">Destroy</a>

Comment: @benjs.1 Try to replicate the behavior in a new app and put its source code somewhere online (repo/archive/...). I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it, in my application.html.erb file I was missing the following lines:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Thank you to all who tried to help

Answer (score 2):

Changing the link's method to `:delete` requires JavaScript.

1. Make sure you require `jquery_ujs` in your `application.js`.

   ```
   //= require jquery_ujs
   ```
2. Make sure JavaScript is enabled in your browser.

Comment: That's already in my application.js, I'm using Firefox so assume JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: I've never had to use javascript to have a delete link.  is this a change in a recent version of rails?

Comment: @MaxWilliams As far as I remember it has always been like this. The only change I'm aware of is that since Rails 3 it uses unobtrusive JS (it outputs `data-method` attribute instead of the ugly `onclick` handler).

Comment: @MaxWilliams - This is javascript be defult included in rails. Links can only create GET requests,  so rails have to tweak the url to contain piggy-backed `_method` param. Without it it is just a usual GET request. When this is passed, it is still GET, but rails will treat it as DELETE

Comment: @MaxWilliams Maybe you're thinking of `button_to` - it will generate the form directly into the markup and doesn't require JS.

Comment: ah, @JiříPospíšil you're half-right: i **was** thinking of link_to, but this does actually convert the link into a js form in the links' onclick method.  So i was wrong earlier when i said i'd not had to use javascript: i'd been using the unobtrusive javascript.